# When does JSF creates a session & what does it puts in a session map?

Tags: jsf-2, httpsession, mojarra

I am running Mojarra 2.2.0.

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

The managed bean action method is-

```
public void action() {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        System.out.println(session.getId()); // not null for stateful views
    }
```

For `stateless` views `session.getId()` throws `NPE`

For views which are not stateless-
Firing a GET request, there is `JSESSIONID=340041C96D5AA446D761C3602F54A76D`

I read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095713/no-session-generation-in-jsf/4096992?noredirect=1#comment60890865_4096992) that-

> For client side state saving mechanism,  JSF won't create the session
>   and will store the view state in a hidden input field with the name
>   javax.faces.ViewState in the form whenever necessary.

Further, it's mentioned here [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834016/when-is-session-created-during-jsf-login)

> JSF will indeed autocreate the session because the JSF view state has
>   to be stored over there. If you set the JSF state saving method to
>   client instead of server, then it won't be stored in session and hence
>   no session needs to be created

I think the above line is a source for trouble for me.

> If you set the JSF state saving method to client instead of server,
>   then it won't be stored in session // FULLY AGREED

and

> hence no session needs to be created. // This confuses because for
>   client side saving mechanism, a session id gets generated by the
>   servlet container & hence there is a session associated with the
>   request.

In reference to the discussion which I had with BalusC in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095713/no-session-generation-in-jsf/4096992?noredirect=1#comment60890865_4096992),
I created a HttpSessionListener-

```
@WebListener
public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        Thread.dumpStack();
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {

    }

}
```

See below attached screenshots(these 2 screenshots are for version 2.0.3, there must have been an old bug due to which the session was getting created)-

[image]

[image]

Libraby (Mojarra 2.2.0)-
[image]

Comment: @BalusC: Eclipse IDE auto downloaded it for me. I am attaching the screenshot too.

Comment: @BalusC: Sorry for this silly mistake. I thought removing the 2.0.3 library from the buildpath will remove them completely. For Mojarra 2.2.0, now the same HttpSession Listener is not getting called. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BalusC: Ahh, I see. Now, I got it. I think the source for this whole trouble was the version number.

Comment: @BalusC: It would have indeed great on your side if the version number was included in your answers.

Comment: @BalusC: So there will be no session map. Right.

Comment: @BalusC: But I am amazed, even when you knew sessionMap wont be created, why you wrote this in the comment "t's still not clear why SessionMap.put is invoked while client side state saving is enabled. There's more between FacesServlet.service and SessionMap.put which you omitted." What are you actually referring to here, what did I actually omit?

Comment: @BalusC: First of all, it would be insane on my part to answer it by myself and then accepting it, since you help me to resolve it. Secondly, given the version no 2.0.3 with which I was working, then I think I was on the right track considering that the session was indeed getting created. Thirdly, I dont debug things like that. Had I worked with 2.2.0, the session.getId() in the action method, would have thrown NPE and then it would have been absolutely cleared to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *When does JSF creates a session*

Eaiest way to naildown this is creating a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html), putting a debug breakpoint on `sessionCreated()` method and inspecting the call stack who needed to get the session for the first time (and thus implicitly needs to create it).

In below example you will see a chain of `getSession()` calls in the call stack. You will see that `FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView()` method is the one calling it for the first time.

[image]

After you click on `FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView()` line in debugger's call stack, you will get into its source code (Maven will load source code automatically, otherwise you need to manually attach it).

[image]

You see, when server side state saving is enabled and the view to render is not transient ([stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890995/what-is-the-usefulness-of-statelessness-in-jsf)), then JSF will implicitly create the session, just to ensure it's created on time in order to save the view (if the session was created later, e.g. during render response phase, you would otherwise risk exceptions like this [Adding <h:form> causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072311/adding-hform-causes-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-create-a-session)).

You'll in the source code also immediately see that when the state saving method is set to client, or when the view is stateless as in `<f:view transient="true">`, then JSF won't anymore implicitly create the session. Older JSF versions may do that as you figured, but this is to be accounted as a bug and ought to be fixed in a newer version.

If you would like to ensure statelessness and avoid accidental/unforeseen session creation, then you could just `throw new IllegalStateException()` inside `sessionCreated()` method. When that happens, you just have to look in call stack who's responsible for creating the session and then fix/change the code to not do that anymore.

---

> *what does it puts in a session map?*

Under the covers, [`ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap--) delegates to `HttpSession#setAttribute()`/`getAttribute()`/`removeAttribute()`. You can listen on those methods using a [`HttpSessionAttributeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html).

In below example you will see that `ViewScopeContextManager.getContextMap()` line calls `SessionMap#put()` method in order to put something in the session map. When you unfold the `event` argument, you will see the session attribute name and value, which is `com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewContexts` and an empty `ConcurrentHashMap` respectively.

[image]

Indeed, I was using a `@Named @ViewScoped` which was referenced by an value expression on the particular page (you see EL resolver and Weld resolver further down in call stack). When you click `ViewScopeContextManager.getContextMap()` line in call stack, you'll see that it was just preparing a map in session scope in order to store view scoped beans.

[image]

That's just one example. There are more things which could be stored in the session. Using a debugger this way and inspecting the associated source code will tell a lot about the *Why*.